# Making http protocol handler start different browsers based on URL mask

Tags: google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, file-association

At work we are using Sharepoint which doesn't like non IE browsers that much. Currently I'm using Chrome or Firefox for most of my surfing needs, but I'd like to launch Internet Explorer for a few specific sites. I have tried IE tab, but it doesn't work 100% (rich text editor in list views is rendering comments as HTML instead of RTF)

Does anyone know any software that I can set as my default browser, and based on the URL clicked (in Outlook mail mostly) will launch either Chrome or Internet Explorer?

Comment: I think the best solution here would be to have the default program for opening url objects from outlook be a batch script that checks if the URL is from a certain domain using regex and then opens a browser appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Browser Chooser](http://browserchooser.codeplex.com/) is close to what you want.  I use it at work where there are several sites (like Sharepoint) that only work in IE.  It can open intranet URLs in a certain browser, but I set it to my default browser and hit the number of the browser I want.